# SQL Server 2014 installation taking long time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

Normally our SQL Server installation takes 5 - 10 minutes, but on several of our recent server builds on vmWare, the SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition setup has been taking a very long time. I have intermittently had the problem with 2014 with SP1 and without SP1 (RTM). With SP1 it was stuck for about an hour
`on "Install_SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_Action: Create Shortcuts. Creating shortcuts"` and the CPUs were at about 20% while it was stuck running the installer service. This time it has been stuck for 1.5 hours on `Install_sql_engine_core_shared_Cpu64_Action: RemoveSupportFiles_64. Removing temporary files` and the CPUs are at 0%.

The Summary.txt file states the following, but I didn't cancel the installation:

```
Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Adv_SSMS:        SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SSMS:            SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for ComponentUpdate: SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC:            SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Writer:          SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Browser:         SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
```

Last time the same thing happened but it finished and the Summary.txt file showed successful installation.

I am using a `.config file` to run the installations and have:

```
FEATURES="SQLEngine, ADV_SSMS"
```

Has anyone else experienced similar problems and do you have any suggestions?

Comment: could you take a vm snapshot and test to see if it works from the GUI, secondly, how about just installing just the server or client first.  That'll help reduce the scope to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, Ali. Yeah, I thought about that and will try to do some more testing  tomorrow. It seems to always install fast from the GUI, but it's nice to have the automated installation and we haven't had problems with it until recently.

Comment: It was still running after 2.5 hours, so I ended the task and was able to install SSMS from the setup.exe in 2 minutes. I then used my script without the ADV_SSMS and it finished in 1 minute, so maybe it's something with the ADV_SSMS feature option in the config file.

Comment: so from what you're saying SSMS installs very quickly from both command prompt and GUI.  You said it was running after 2.5 hours, which method were you using?  You were installing the engine and SSMS correct, and the Engine did not install per my understanding.  Please confirm.

Comment: Ali, it runs for a long time or hangs when I use the command line and FEATURES="SQLEngine, ADV_SSMS", but if I first install SSMS from the setup.exe GUI and then just use FEATURES="SQLEngine" from the command line, it installs in 1-2 minutes.

Comment: We installed SSMS on the vmWare template to work around this problem.